# Use results of an =cell formula as starting point for another formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a formula that gives me a cell as it's result. For example in `A1` `=CELL("address", C2)` gives me the answer `$c$2`.

I want my next formula to start from this result. For example `=IF(<result>=2,TRUE,FALSE)`. So in the example above it would be `=IF(c2=2,TRUE,FALSE)`.

So the question is, what am I writing instead of `<result>`.

Hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

Use INDIRECT()

```
=IF(INDIRECT(<result>)=2,TRUE,FALSE)
```